# MQTT over Websocket request / x-amzn-ErrorType: ForbiddenException

Tags: websocket, arduino, mqtt, esp8266, aws-iot

I am using [ESP8266-Websocket](https://github.com/morrissinger/ESP8266-Websocket), [aws-sdk-arduino](https://github.com/heskew/aws-sdk-arduino)(cleaned branch) and [pubsubclient](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient) to try to comunicate with aws iot mqtt service using websockets.

My question is about the first connection request. I am using this browser app as reference https://github.com/awslabs/aws-iot-examples and the sign code from aws-sdk-arduino (that works fine calling the aws iot restful api)

My request was this (after connect to the endpoint at 443 port):

```
GET wss://ENDPOINT.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mqtt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AWSKEY%2F20160318%2Fus-west-2%2Fiotdevicegateway%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20160318T183246Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=a1f0d7b58983f9dff7e3bf6cab062db3243ebafc990803a018c6a23433891404 HTTP/1.1
host: ENDPOINT.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: file://
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: D2alJOyUkBlR+8yhv2UBLg==
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: mqtt
```

but I keep getting

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
content-type: application/json
content-length: 241
date: Fri, 18 Mar 2016 18:34:57 GMT
x-amzn-RequestId: f2edfe83-1bbc-4481-97e0-39ccfc4d1c2f
connection: Keep-Alive
x-amzn-ErrorType: ForbiddenException:
```

am i missing some request header parameter? is there anyway to get a better feedback from x-amzn-ErrorType: ForbiddenException? am i messing up in the sign process? (even though it works for rest call)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I've finally got response status 101 switching protocols \o/

when you are building the request, it must be:

```
GET /mqtt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AWSKEY%2F20160318%2Fus-west-2%2Fiotdevicegateway%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20160318T183246Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=a1f0d7b58983f9dff7e3bf6cab062db3243ebafc990803a018c6a23433891404 HTTP/1.1
```

instead of

```
GET wss://ENDPOINT.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mqtt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AWSKEY%2F20160318%2Fus-west-2%2Fiotdevicegateway%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20160318T183246Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=a1f0d7b58983f9dff7e3bf6cab062db3243ebafc990803a018c6a23433891404 HTTP/1.1
```

the js example that I was following was using the full path. When I got the request built by chrome (throught developer tools) the path was full as well. Just after use firebug I got the real request that browser was sending to the server (with short path).

now I can continue to try the solution (mqtt over websockets at esp8266) :-) if it works, I will share the code ;-)

Comment: thanks. I had seen that library, did not make the connection tho. Will give it a try.